# How to set up Automapper global options to allow destination values to be null when source is null

Tags: c#, automapper

I have next classes where I want to use Automapper and if source property is null, then set destination property as null as well:

```cs
public class CompanyTest
{
    public Guid? Id { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public PersonTest? CEO { get; set; }
    public List<PersonTest> People { get; set; } = new();
}

public class CompanyPatchTest
{
    public string? CompanyName { get; set; }
    public PersonPatchTest? CEO { get; set; }
    public List<PersonPatchTest>? People { get; set; }
}

public class PersonTest
{
    public Guid? Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<PersonTest> Children { get; set; } = new();
}

public class PersonPatchTest
{
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public List<PersonPatchTest>? Children { get; set; }
}
```

and I have created next xunit test that is failing:

```cs
using Xunit;
using AutoMapper;
using FluentAssertions;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace UnitTests.Tests;

public class AutomapperTests
{
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;

    public AutomapperTests()
    {
        var services = new ServiceCollection();

        services.AddAutoMapper(x =>
        {
            x.AddProfile(new ProfileTest());
        });

        var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
        _mapper =  serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IMapper>();
    }

    [Fact]
    public void ShouldSetNullValue()
    {
        var company = new CompanyTest
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
            CompanyName = "OriginalName",
            CEO = new()
            { 
                Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                Name= "Name",
                Children = new()
                {
                    new PersonTest
                    {
                        Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                        Name= "Name",
                    }
                }
            },
        };

        var source = new CompanyPatchTest
        {
            CompanyName = "CompanyName",
            CEO = null,
        };

        company = _mapper.Map<CompanyPatchTest, CompanyTest>(source, company);
        company.CEO.Should().BeNull();
    }
}
```

My profile is the next one:

```cs
public class ProfileTest : Profile
{
    public ProfileTest()
    {
        CreateMap<CompanyTest, CompanyPatchTest>();
        CreateMap<PersonTest, PersonPatchTest>();

        CreateMap<CompanyPatchTest, CompanyTest>(MemberList.Source)
            .ForMember(d => d.CEO, op => op.AllowNull());

        CreateMap<PersonPatchTest, PersonTest>(MemberList.Source);
    }
}
```

If I remove `CreateMap<PersonPatchTest, PersonTest>(MemberList.Source);` line then it works. But I won't be able to customize that mapping.

Also, it'd be nice if this could be set up as a global setting for all properties.

I have tried using `AllowNullDestinationValues` but it is not working

```cs
...
public AutomapperTests()
    {
        var services = new ServiceCollection();

        services.AddAutoMapper(x =>
        {
            x.AddProfile(new ProfileTest());
            x.AllowNullCollections = true;
            x.AllowNullDestinationValues = true;
        });

        var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
        _mapper =  serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IMapper>();
    }
...
```

If this cannot be done using Automapper, do you know any other tool that could achieve this?

Autmapper version: 12.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug that was solved in version 12.0.1. You don't need any settings for that test to pass. The default for `AllowNullDestinationValues` is [`true`](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/9081e27f38fe3b4045d95dae0369dff18dada984/src/AutoMapper/ProfileMap.cs#L18).

https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/pull/4083